# Linear Regression.

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, statistical-inference

I have been going through the book called elements of statistical learning, in which I came across the given below equation for the linear regression solution.
$$RSS(β)=(Y−Xβ)^T(Y−Xβ)$$
on expanding we have
$$RSS(β)=Y^TY−β^TX^TY−Y^TXβ+β^TX^TXβ$$.

now we have $$Y^TXβ=(Y^TXβ)^T=β^TX^TY$$. since $Y^TXβ$ is scalar.

Hence we have $$RSS(β)=Y^TY−2β^TX^TY+β^TX^TXβ$$ or $$RSS(β)=Y^TY−2Y^TXβ+β^TX^TXβ$$

now they say that they are diff $RSS(β)$ wrt to $β$ which yields $−2X^T(Y−Xβ)$, how is this differentiation achieved. In the sense how can you differentiate with respect to matrix to achieve this. 
Thanks in advance, I have been breaking my head over this.
Could you please help me with the sources where I might get some clue with respect to this operation.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: Thank you i did not know this feature existed as I am new to this forum.